# gsutil rsync returns error when called by Python 3.5.2, but okay from command line

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have a gsutil rsync call which works fine from the command line, but when called by subprocess.run returns an stderr of
'CommandException: The rsync command accepts at most 2 arguments.'

I don't find this limitation anywhere in the gsutil documentation.

My args are
['/Users/username/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil', 'rsync', '-CderU', '-x' '.*/[.].*$', '/Users/username/Documents/_Projects/Active Projects/myFolder', 'gs://myBucket/myFolder', '2>>', '/Users/username/Library/Logs/gCloud/2016_12_07.log']

When I run my full command through shlex, it comes out as listed above.  I have also combined '-CderU' and '-x' into '-CderUx', but receive the same result.

I am running Python 3.5.2 and have the latest version of gsutil under Mac OS 10.11.6.

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

gsutil doesn't (yet) support Python 3.x.x - it currently only supports Python 2.7.  So you'll need to use that version of Python.  It's documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#alt-install), among other places.